# Modular inverse of a $2\times2$ matrix with unknown variable

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

If I have   $$B=\begin{pmatrix} 3&9\\9&x\end{pmatrix}\bmod 10$$

How would I find the inverse for all $x$ unknowns. I wrote

To find $B^{-1}$,  $$B^{-1}=\frac{1}{3x-81} \begin{pmatrix} x&-9\\-9&3\end{pmatrix}$$

and that if $x$ is odd, $\det(b)$ is even and has no inverse modulo $10$

That leaves $x=-2,2,4,-4,6,-6,8,-8,10,-10$ I think

for $x=-8$ and $x=2$, $\det(b)=5$ and has no inverse modulo $10$

am I going right so far. some of the x values have equal determinants like -6,4 both have 1 as the determinant so would I have to evaluate them both and what x values would I need to evaluate because I'm pretty sure its not all of them.

I would need to find say for $x=-4 \det(b)=7$ and inverse $7$ mod $10$ is $3$. So would need also need to times the matrix like

$$=3\begin{pmatrix} 3&-9\\-9&3\end{pmatrix}\bmod 10$$ to find the matrix for $x=-4$

Edit:

For x=4 The inverse is 1 Hence for x=4

$B^{-1}$=$$=1\begin{pmatrix} 4&-9\\-9&3\end{pmatrix}\bmod 10$$ = $\begin{pmatrix} 4&-9\\-9&3\end{pmatrix}\bmod 10$

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure what this means, would it be ok to provide a little bit more detail i'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First modulo $10$, you only have the even values:
$$x=\pm 2,\;\pm4.$$ There remains to check whether or not the corresponding determinant is a unit mod. $10$.
Next, we can make a table of values:
$$\begin{array}{r|rrrr}
x&+2&-2&+4&-4 \\
\hline
3x-1& 5&3&1&-3 \\
\hline
(3x-1)^{-1}& \text{—}& -3&1&3
\end{array}$$

Comment: Sorry what do mean by your first sentence, and also was it 3x-81. Does that mean I would only need to check +-2 +-4 and not the 6,8 and 10. Thank you for the help

Comment: Sorry,  I added a sentence to my initial phrasing, and I put it in the wrong place. We only have to consider these values because modulo $10$, we have $\pm 6=\mp4$ and $\pm 8=\mp2$. As to the determinant, $81\equiv 1\mod 10$, that's why I used this form, simpler to calculate with.

Comment: ahh right thank you that makes sense so I'd only have to to the -2 +4 -4 and also was I right with not doing the odd x values?

Comment: Yes, because in this case $3x-1$ can't be a unit since it is even.

Comment: Thank you so much just a last question what would I multiply to get $B^-1$ for example for x=-4 det(3x-1)=-3 and the inverse is 3 so would I do 3(3,-9  3,-9) or would I do 3(-4,9  -9,3), meaning would I put x=-4 or x=3 in the matrix bracket?

Comment: You put $x=4$, but the result is not what you've written, but $(4,-9,-9,3)$, which corresponds to what's in your post. Of course, you should check you indeed  obtain the inverse.

Comment: Hi sorry to be a pain but one last question I made an edit at the bottom of my post relating to your response I think it would make it easier to explain. So for  x=4 I multiply by the inverse 1 and use x value in the matrix of 4. and multiplying them together gets the bottom answer or did I make a mistake?

Comment: You're not a pain at all! Your answer is correct, I've checked the product of the two matrices is indeed the unit matrix.

Comment: Hi thank you for helping so much its just that I have c1=(4,3) c2=(3,5) and AB=C so when I do A=CB^-1 I for x=4 in the editget A= (9,7   3,8) but when I do AB to verify for C I dont get it with the bottom right entry for the matrix